# How do singular values of a matrix change when left multiplying by a row vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, singular-values

Suppose I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{A \times B}$ with SVD $M = U S V^T$.

For a given vector $p \in \mathbb{R}^A$, can I compute the SVD of $p^T S V^T$ as a function of the original singular values $S$ and original right singular vectors $V$?

Comment: The result is a row vector, so you don't need an SVD.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "need."  I want to relate the SVD of the row vector $p^T S V^T$ to the SVD of $M$.

Comment: I'm just saying that the result has dim 1. The singular value is the norm of the result, the right singular vector is just the normalized result, and the left is the scalar 1. Other than that, the remaining right singular vectors are arbitrary because they're all in the nullspace. Also, SVDs aren't unique (the matrices can be permuted), so $p^TSV^T$ isn't unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the svd of the $A\times B$ matrix $M$, $M=USV^\top$, and the $1\times B$ matrix $L:=p^\top SV^\top$, then the svd of $L$ can be worked out from that of $M$.

The singular values of $L$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $LL^\top$ where $$\sigma^2v=LL^\top v=p^\top SV^\top VS^\top p=p^\top S^\top Sp=[r^2]$$ where $$r^2=p_1^2\sigma_1^2+\cdots+p_n^2\sigma_n^2$$ Thus there is only one right singular vector with singular value $r$.

The related eigenvector is that of $L^\top L$, so $$\sigma^2v=L^\top Lv=VS^\top pp^\top SV^\top pv=(p^\top SV^\top v)(VS^\top p)$$ so $v$ is the unit vector in the direction of $VS^\top p=p_1\sigma_1u_1+\cdots+p_n\sigma_nu_n$, where $u_n$ are the singular vectors of $M$.

Conclusion: The SVD of $L$ is $$\underbrace{[1]}_{1\times1}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}r,0,\ldots,0\end{bmatrix}}_{1\times B}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&\ldots&v_n\\&\cdots\end{bmatrix}}_{B\times B}$$ The first row of the new $V^\top$ matrix is the $v$ vector and the other rows are any set of orthonormal vectors (so it is not unique).

Comment: This is technically correct, but since $p^TSV^T$ *isn't unique* for a fixed $p$ and $M$, I don't think it matters that it came from an SVD. At that point it's just describing how to find an SVD for an arbitrary row vector.

Comment: In fact, if $M$ has a duplicate singular value then there are *infinite* possible SVDs. This doesn't matter if $U$ is left in, but replacing it with $p$ means $pSV^T$ isn't even well-defined if "SVD of $M$" is the only requirement of $USV^T$.

Comment: Singular values *are* unique and those of $p^TSV^T$ are 0 and $r$ and as in the answer, $r$ is uniquely given by $p_i$ and $\sigma_i$. What you're implying is that the new $V$ is not unique, but I acknowledge that in the answer. The asker did not imply that the SVD is unique, they're taking some SVD expansion and elaborates on that.

Comment: I'm saying that $p^TSV^T$ itself isn't unique because of the very large number of possible SVDs for $M$, regardless of the rank of $M$. It might as well be an arbitrary row vector. (Please see my full response.)

Comment: @Chrystomath , one quick clarification question. When you write, "$v$ is the unit vector in the direction of $VS^T p$, where $u_n$ are the singular vectors of $M$", you mean the *right* singular vectors of $M$, correct? You use the variable $u_n$, which suggests to me the *left* singular vectors of $M$. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes. I use $u_n$ because that's how I learned them. And the $v_i$ are the components of $v$.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment below your question (and in @Chrystomath's response), the general form of an SVD of a row vector $x^T\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ is:

$\left[1\right]\ \left[||x||\ \ 0^{n-1}\right]\ \left[\dfrac{x}{||x||}\ \ \ U_{\bot x}\right]^T\tag{1}$

Where $0^{n-1}$ is $n-1$ zeros and $U_{\bot x}$ is any orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathbb{R}x$, i.e., the remaining part of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that's orthogonal to $x$. (In general, both $0^{n-1}$ and $U_{\bot x}$ can be removed to create a truncated SVD.)

---

That said, $p^TSV^T$ can only be *loosely* interpreted in terms of $M$, to an extent that it's largely irrelevant that $S$ and $V$ came from an SVD of $M$.

1. Assuming that $M$ is square, if $USV^T$ is an SVD of $M$, then so is $(UP^T)(PSP^T)(PV^T)$ for any permutation $P$. This is because $UP^T$ and $VP^T$ are still unitary, and $PSP^T$ is still diagonal containing exactly the singular values of $M$. (This is easily extended to the rectangular case.) This means that, if $p^TSV^T$ is a possible outcome of your algorithm, then so is $p^TPSV^T$ for any permutation $P$.
2. If a singular value has multiplicity $k$ then the corresponding spaces of singular vectors have dimension $k$. This means that *any* orthonormal basis for the corresponding spaces can be used in $U$ and $V$. For example, suppose $M=I$. Since $UIU^T=I$ for any orthogonal $U$, this means that $UIU^T$ is a possible SVD of $I$. So, $p^TU^T$ would be a possible outcome of your algorithm when $M=I$, i.e., literally any orthogonal transformation of $p^T$. (The same principle can be applied more locally with repeated singular values.)

In summary, $p^TSV^T$ itself *is not* well-defined in terms of $M$; you just need to multiply the whole thing out once you have $S$ and $V$. This essentially reduces the problem to finding an SVD for an arbitrary row vector.

---

(An exception to all of this is if $p$ is dependent on $U$, in which case the question is completely different. If that's the case, my answer would be quite a bit different.)

---

**Edit:** Just to show that these concerns aren't pedantry, here is a working demonstration.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of random values. In general, $A$ will be invertible; however, $AA^{-1}$ will differ from $I$ slightly, due to numerical errors. This will cause the singular values of $AA^{-1}$ to vary slightly from $1$, affecting how iterative algorithms generate $U$ and $V$. This simulates how the SVD algorithm ends up choosing an arbitrary basis when a singular value is repeated.

The following function in the R programming language demonstrates this:

```
f <- function(p) {
  # Generate a random matrix
  A <- matrix(rnorm(ncol(p)^2,0,1),c(ncol(p),ncol(p)))

  # Approximate I with AA^-1
  I <- A%*%solve(A)

  # Compute the SVD of I
  I.svd <- svd(I)

  # Compute p D V^T
  val <- p%*%diag(I.svd$d)%*%t(I.svd$v)

  # Return errors
  list(p.error=norm(p-val,type='F'),I.error=norm(diag(ncol(p))-I,type='F'))
}


# Call f with the row vector [1,2,3]
f(cbind(1,2,3))
```

`f` approximates $M=I$ by multiplying a random matrix by its inverse, then computes $pSV^T$ using the provided row vector $p$ and the SVD of $M$. Ideally, the result should be close to $p=pII^T$, but because slight perturbation has a large effect on the SVD algorithm, the result is nowhere near $p$.

Below is a table of 10 sequential calls to $f$ with $p=[1,2,3]$. The first column is the error between $p$ and $pSV^T$ and the second is the error between $AA^{-1}$ and $I$. (Both using the Frobenius norm.)

```
      p.error  I.error     
 [1,] 3.844951 5.551115e-16
 [2,] 4.978845 1.073535e-15
 [3,] 3.04258  3.002225e-16
 [4,] 6.458657 4.014976e-16
 [5,] 4.472136 5.087681e-16
 [6,] 1.414214 2.237726e-16
 [7,] 6.224307 4.007774e-16
 [8,] 3.260453 6.426114e-16
 [9,] 3.545585 3.521788e-16
[10,] 3.406453 1.428806e-16
```

Notice how the error in approximating $I$ is $O(10^{-16})$, whereas the error between $pSV^T$ and its "intuitive" result $p$ is $O(||p||)$. The latter errors completely disappear if you use $I$ with no perturbations, however.